# Is it possible to retrieve list of Capabilities

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is is possible to retrieve a list of all capabilities which can be checked.

Currently https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/capabilities/Capability.html only contains static Capabilities bu no getList() or something.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible for now. You will need to check separately each of them.

Comment: Yes this is what I'm also thinking looking at the API.

Comment: Note I created this issue http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8404 to add this feature.